# Winforms DatagridView Get clicked Cell Value only from 1-st Column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I can get the **value of a clicked datagridView** cell like this:

```
    private void dgvCountryHits_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var cell = dgvCountryHits.CurrentCell;

        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}", cell.Value));
    }
```

**How do i allow clicking ONLY on Column[0]?**
Ignoring clicks on the rest of the columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know which column it is you can use `e.ColumnIndex == 1`.

See this link: [DataGridViewCellEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs(v=vs.110).aspx)